# Custom customer attribute not being created

Tags: customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, magento2.2.3

I have written the following script to create a custom customer attribute in Magento 2.2.3. When I run `setup:upgrade` magento tells me data was installed but the attribute does not appear in `eav_attribute` table.

```
<?php

namespace MyNameSpace\StoreName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'store_real_name',
            [
            'type'         => 'varchar',
            'label'        => 'Store Name',
            'input'        => 'text',
            'required'     => false,
            'visible'      => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position'     => 999,
            'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $storeName = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'store_real_name');


        $storeName->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
        ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit']

        );
        $storeName->save();
    }
}
```

I have used an identical script to create other attributes without issue, but for some reason this one won't save. I have tried to disable and enable the module and re-run `setup:upgrade` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your script looks Ok, please try to execuse: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following commands after do major changes in your code. Example if you create script than you might run upgrade command.

Commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean or php bin/magento cache:flush
```

The above commands should be run in console.

Comment: Yes, run all of those commands, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code it will create Customer Attribute

```
<?php
namespace MyNameSpace\StoreName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'store_real_name', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Store Name',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $storeName = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'store_real_name')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_address_edit']
        ]);

        $storeName->save();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this didn't work either, exactly same result as original post. I've checked the usual logs to see if there's any issues but cannot see anything.